# Click event on Donut Highchart with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts

I'm using the Highchart librairy with GWT to display multiseries Donut charts.

I would like to be able to click on one point (one series' subpart) and retrieve within the event handler the name of this point.

I tried "setPointLegendItemClickEventHandler" in the "PiePlotOption" that I set to my series but that's not working.

I can't find anything in the documentation that helps me.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add click event listeners in your highcharts. For capturing the click event on the inner level series, add the following code in the Series (browsers) tag inside highcharts:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(event) {
             alert("Name: "+this.name + " X: " + this.y + " Y: " + this.x);
        }
    }  
}
```

and for capturing the click on on the outer level 2 series, add the following inside plotOptions>Pie tag:

```
point: {
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                 alert(this.name);
            }
        }  
}
```

You will get the name as well as X, Y values of each point clicked.

**[See the DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rugq8uL5/)**

Comment: Actualy this solution is all over the net but does not help much as I'm not using Javascript (unfortunatly, oh gosh...) but GWT. However, I finally managed to find the solution. (cf. my answer) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. See below :

```
myDonutChart.setSeriesPlotOptions(new SeriesPlotOptions().setPointClickEventHandler(new PointClickEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClick(PointClickEvent pointClickEvent) {
        // log pointClickEvent.getPointName();
        return false;
    }
}));
```

There you go.